# What's the best way to determine success metrics?

Tags: metrics

You have a user pain point that you're trying to fix. There's a 50% drop-off on this one particular page, and your job is to reduce that. How do you determine that your design is a success? When the drop-off goes down to 5%? 10%? 15%?

Answer (score 2):

I believe any drop-off can be considered successful.

The person who voted to close this question is right about the fact it's opinion based. You have to determine what you will consider a success.

It is hard however to form an opinion about that based on percentages. You can however translate it to Return On Investment.

Let's say the page you speak of is the checkout page and of the 50% of visitors that do go through with the purchase ALL of them finish the checkout (for sake of keeping this easier to calculate).

So what if in 2015 100 visitors visited this checkout. 50 visitors actually bought something. Revenue for 2015 was $500. That means a visitor is worth on average $10 a year.
So if you decrease the drop-off with let's say 10%, 10% of 50 people is 5 persons, that will mean 55 visitors now made a purchase. So revenue for 2016 will be $550. That's a revenue increase of 10%.

So what sounds better. A 10% decrease of the dropoff rate or a 10% increase of revenue.

I personally like the sound of the latter better.

So find out what your ROI can be (for example revenue), see what figure you'll think can be considered successful within that metric and calculate that back to a decrease in drop-off rates.

Measuring your ROI isn't often as straightforward as my example. You'll often have a drop-off at other pages too. But the nice thing is, some UX adjustments have effect over multiple pages and effect on multiple departments.
For example: if you make your checkout more clear, this will also decrease the number of calls to customer support. And this will have a whole lot of other effects on the costs and what not. For these types of measurements you'll often find yourself guessing. But you have statistical methods like [confidence level](http://www.measuringu.com/blog/ci-10things.php) and [significant difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) to give it that scientific support. But that's a whole other ball game that often makes your head hurt.

Comment: This question goes to the heart of how technology provides business value, and how that value can be quantified--and that is important for every development and UX decision that we make. Paul's response moved this from opinion to a solid basis for determining the value. I regret that this question was closed because we need to learn how to bring defensible justification to our development activities.

Comment: I've once sat in a full day course from NN Group hosted by Kate Meyers. It's very valuable on this topic and I could recommend it. https://www.nngroup.com/courses/measuring-ux/